# Layer 3 network, multiple internet connections

Tags: routing, vlan, layer3, hp

I'm using a Procurve 5406zl (J8697A) layer 3 switch with multiple vlans:

**VLANs:**

- v10 Main Network 10.1.4.1
- v12 Wireless 10.1.8.1
- v13 Restricted Wireless 10.0.0.1
- v14 Tech 192.168.7.1
- v50 Internet 192.168.10.254

**And Untangle with 3 nics:**

- External (Uverse)
- Internal (LAN)
- Primary IP: 192.168.10.1 /24

IP Aliases:

- 10.1.4.0 /22
- 10.1.8.0 /22
- 10.1.12.0 /22
- 192.168.7.0 /24
- 10.0.0.0 /20
- DMZ (DSL Connection, this connection we're doing away with)
- eth3 (New fiber connection)

**And Static Routes:**

- Target: 10.1.4.0 - Gateway: 192.168.10.254
- Target: 10.1.8.0- Gateway: 192.168.10.254
- Target: 192.168.7.0 - Gateway: 192.168.10.254
- Target: 10.0.0.0 - Gateway: 192.168.10.254

**Changes I'm looking to make:**

I'd like to start utilizing the new fiber connection added to eth3 interface.

I'd like to have all of the VLANs to start using the eth3 it except for VLAN 13 which is our public wifi id like for it to continue to use the "External" interface.

What do I need to do in order to start utilizing this new connection on eth3?

Comment: I'd invest into a L3 switch which supports VRF, your use case is exact fit for VRF.

Comment: You should put more details on the following:
 1.
What is the external IP of your Untangle box's external interface and how is it connected to the DSL? (I dont need your public IP but the way it is configred)

 2.
What is the setup of the eth3 interface? is it layer 2 interface or layer 3?

 3.
Please share your static route configuration as what you have described is not clear.

 4.
How much down-time can you afford to do this migration?

Comment: 5.
Do you have any other services running on the network?

 6.
Can you change IP addresses of your subnets and user machines?

 7.
Is there any reason to choose the /22 sbnet for your user VLANs?

 8.
Do you have any server VLAN in your network? What servers do you have?

 
I am assuming you still need both your users and public wifi to use the Untangle box. Is this correct?

I tried drawing your current setup and the above questions popped up in my head. It will help if you draw your setup and attach it here. (Please dont include public IPs or other revealing info about your setup).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will require a "policy-based routing"-esque configuration, since you'll essentially be routing based on source address/subnet.

This should be possible with [WAN balancer](http://www.untangle.com/store/wan-balancer-conf.html) if memory serves, but it's been a while so I recommend looking at it's requirements first. (i.e. requires separate cards for each WAN connection)